# calc() with jQuery (background-position)

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-position, calc

How can i replace CSS calc() with jQuery?

```
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
    posY = Math.floor(0.2 * scrollPos);

$('.background-layer').css('background-position', '50% calc(50% + ' + posY + 'px)');
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with this code, and what is `this` (or `$(this)`) in your code? Please post sufficient information, and "*[mcve]*" code, that we can understand and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
<div class="lala">
sdasd
</div>
 var posY=50;
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lala").css('background-position-y',"50%").css('background-position-
   y','+='+posY+'px')

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5946szm/1/

Comment: $(this).css('background-position',$(this).css('background-position').split(' ')[0] 50%).css('background-position',$(this).css('background-position').split(' ')[0]  '+='+posY+'px');

Comment: It's not working. You just split two values. That split returns just '50%'. I did it before.

Comment: I don't want to use background-position-y rule, because Firefox doesn't support it to 48 version (http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-position-x-y).